# RestKit can't map an object with 'NULL' result

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have this problem with `RestKit` that I can't figure out. I'm trying to map an object with a `null` result, but the `RestKit` could not handle the object for some reason. I know that I'm doing something wrong, but I just can't figure out what.

**This is the response that I get from the service:**

`{"responseError":null}`

**This is the ResponseError.h file:**

```
@interface ResponseError : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger applicationErrorCode;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *developerMessage;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *userMessage;
@end
```

**This is the ResponseWithError.h file:**

```
@interface ResponseWithError : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,strong) ResponseError *responseError;
@end
```

**This is the mapping of the object:**

```
RKObjectMapping *responseErrorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ResponseError class]];
[responseErrorMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"applicationErrorCode" : @"applicationErrorCode", @"developerMessage" : @"developerMessage",@"userMessage" : @"userMessage"}];

RKRelationshipMapping *responseErrorRelationMapping = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"responseError" toKeyPath:@"responseError" withMapping:responseErrorMapping];


RKObjectMapping *checkR = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ResponseWithError class]];
    [checkR addPropertyMapping:[responseErrorRelationMapping copy]];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:checkR
method:RKRequestMethodPOST pathPattern:[RequestStringBuilder approveStatementChecks]  keyPath: nil
statusCodes: RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]];
```

**This is the error i'm getting from RestKit:**

```
"No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched."
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Wain, maybe you know how to solve this?

Comment: Is the status code returned by the server an HTTP error code in the range 400-499?